# Is is possible to access a React component inside an array map function using ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm rendering React Components using array map function

```
//I need to access the element here
elements.map( element => {

      //And here 

      return <Sample ref = { e => this.myRef = e} /> 
  }
```

When I try to access this.myRef, it returns undefined. What is the right way to access the DOM object of `<Sample/>` ?

Comment: You never set `this.e`.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I corrected it

Comment: Shouldnt it just be `<Sample ref={this.myRef} />`?  Also, you would probably want an array of refs, or something like that, so that each ref is mapped to a unique instance instead of all of them being the same ref.

Comment: Oh I see. Let me see search more about array of refs. BTW I'm using callback refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

Comment: Ah yes - so the format of the ref should be fine, but you will probably have issues with multiple elems with the same ref.

Comment: <Sample ref = {e => this.myRefArray[index] = e} /> . I did this, but when I tried to access this.myRefArray[index], it is returning undefined. Is there any trick to have access to elements inside array of refs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map can iterate through multiple index and every time you are iterating you are overwriting this.myRef and eventually this.myRef at the end of iteration will have last index ref only. Please find the snippet useful.

```
   constructor(){
       //Initialise this.myRef to be an array.
       this.myRef = [];
    }

    //Somewhere when u r iterating
    elements.map( (element,index) => { 
         //Expecting you already imported React
         this.myRef[index] = React.createRef();
         return <Sample ref = { this.myRef[index] } />
     })

//Now log it here just to confirm
console.log(this.myRef);
```

Comment: When I console logged this.myRef as you said. I'm getting an array. But I'm not able to access the elements inside. When Iogged out this.myRef, Its showing an array (An empty array which I'm able to expand to see the contents inside, with title value just being evaluated) with contents inside, but when I try to access this.myRef[0], its returning undefined.

Comment: @JithinKs I'm having the same issue. I'm assuming this is some sort of lifecycle issue, but I'm new to react. Were you able to figure out how to access your array with the index variable within each iteration?

Comment: @Esten Hoping the above code snippet address your issue. This is not with life cycle paradigm / with react this is with the implementation approach.